# Creating a tiered commenting system (efficiently with PHP and MySQL [1 table])

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to have a comment section with replies to comments. The replies will only go one level. For example.

Parent Comment

```
-- Here is a reply
-- Here is another reply
-- It won't go further than this one tier
```

My MySQL looks like this:

> comment_id, comment, parents_id

if parents_id is 0, it is the parent. if it has a number, that number will correspond to the comment_id, as it will be its child.

now, i've done this crappy code below, but it seems the second loop messes it up and only displays the first div correctly with its children. i believe it is because i'm calling mysql_fetch_row twice...

```
$query_show_comments = "SELECT * FROM article_comments WHERE article_id = '$article_id'";
$results_show_comments = mysql_query($query_show_comments);
$num_rows_comments = mysql_num_rows($results_show_comments);

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows_comments; $i++) {
    $comment = mysql_fetch_row($results_show_comments);
    echo "<p>comment_id: $comment[0]</p>";

    if ($comment[5] == 0) {
echo <<<_HTML
    <div class="dispArticle">
        <p><strong>Commenter Name commented @ 11/22/10 10:10:10pm</strong></p>
        <p>$comment[2]</p>
_HTML;

        for ($j = 0; $j < $num_rows_comments; $j++) {
            $replies = mysql_fetch_row($results_show_comments);
            if ($replies[5] > 0 AND $replies[5] == $comment[0]) {
echo <<<_HTML
        <div class="comment"><p><strong>Reply Name replied @ 11/22/10 10:10:10pm</strong></p>
            <p>child_id: $replies[0]</p>
            <p>parent_id: $comment[0]</p>
            <p>$replies[2]</p>
        </div>
        <br />
_HTML;
            }
        }
    }
echo "</div>";
}
```

Been searching for hours and this is what I've found.

1. Use multiple tables (would like to keep it in one table so less queries)
2. Use multiple queries (same as above)
3. Feed into an array first then sort it all out (what if the comments are long and there are a lot? I just did a query AND had to do more server side processing of feeding it into an array, sorting then displaying...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that mysql_fetch_row() will always fetch the next row returned by the query, and that could be in any order.  For what you are doing to work, you would need a post to be followed immediately by its child comments every time.  This is a shaky solution, so I would suggest you use #3 as it is really the same thing as what you are doing.

I also have a couple of suggestions: use mysql_fetch_assoc() over mysql_fetch_row() and use the names of the columns rather than their numbers as this makes the code much more readable and easier to use.  You will have to change your query to order by the ascending parent ID to ensure that all parents are set first.  Then:

```
$query = "query";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$comments = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   if ($row['parent_id']) {
      $comments[$row['parent_id']]['children'][] = $row;
   }
   else {
      $row['children'] = array();
      $comments[$row['comment_id']] = $row;
   }
}
```

Now all of the children are associated with parents.  Just iterate through the array.

Comment: this would work, but i would just question how efficient this would be since its 1.) doing a query 2.) feeding an array (which could be very, very large depending on the size of the comments and a memory hog), 3.) looping again to display.

Comment: The query should not matter much as you have to do it regardless.  If size is a concern, set a limit on the query so only so many comments are displayed.  Do you really have to display every comment?  About the complexity, it's still the same complexity if only iterate through the array once than  if you iterate twice; yes it will double the processing time, but unless this is something like millions of results (in which case you have another problem) it should not be noticeable.  I created this page using the technique above: http://www.gleim.com/accounting/products.php?cat=CPA

Answer (score 0):

It's not too hard. You should store all comments in one table and have parent_id
parent_id of 0 means it's a comment, parent_id > 0 would point to id of a message in the same table for which it's a reply.

You would also have article_id, just like in your current example. 
The trick you need is to do just one SQL select but reference the same table twice.

You sql will be something like this:

```
            SELECT
            M.id as id,
            M.id as com_mid,
            M.post_subject as com_subject,
            M.message_body as com_body,


            M2.id as rpl_mid,
            M2.post_subject as rpl_subject,
            M2.message_body as rpl_body,
            M2.parent_id


            FROM
            MESSAGES AS M
            LEFT JOIN MESSAGES as M2 on M2.parent_message_id = M.id

            WHERE M.article_id = :aid
            AND M.parent_id = 0
            ORDER BY com_mid ASC,
            rpl_mid ASC
```

Then once you get result of this sql, you will easily figure out how to handle the result array to display messages and replies

Answer (score 0):

You need a second query. Here's an example TRYING to use your code.

```
$query_show_comments = "SELECT * FROM article_comments WHERE article_id = '$article_id'";
$results_show_comments = mysql_query($query_show_comments);
$num_rows_comments = mysql_num_rows($results_show_comments);

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows_comments; $i++) {
    $row_comment = mysql_fetch_row($results_show_comments);
    echo "<p>comment_id: $row_comment[0]</p>";

    if ($row_comment[5] == 0) {
echo <<<_HTML
    <div class="dispArticle">
        <p><strong>Commenter Name commented @ 11/22/10 10:10:10pm</strong></p>
        <p>$row_comment[2]</p>
_HTML;

        $query_show_replies = "SELECT * FROM article_comments WHERE parent_id = '$article_id'";
        $result_replies = mysql_query($query_show_replies);
        while( $row_reply = mysql_fetch_row($results_show_comments) ) )
                echo "
                        <div class=\"comment\"><p><strong>Reply Name replied @ 11/22/10 10:10:10pm</strong></p>
                            <p>child_id: $row_reply[0]</p>
                            <p>parent_id: $row_reply[1]</p>
                        </div><br />
                ";
        }
    }
echo "</div>";
}
```

You're doing several things in your code that I don't like to do, not saying it can't be don't that way. My advice is to take a more advanced approach to architecting your web applications:

- Use while() loops when reading data from queries, it's more error tolerant
- don't use the "echo <<<" blocks because it makes code harder to read
- technically speaking, you'll want to use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on all output to a web page, so the <<< shouldn't be used anyways
- better yet, use a template system to extricate your markup (view) from your PHP, conside [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) because it's easy even if performance isn't quite stellar
- in fact, while you're at it, consider abstracting your data code into a [separate layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220473/php-sql-query-results/4220816#4220816)
- no matter how you get the data, you shouldn't rely on indexed fields when you're using a SELECT *.. because the order could change. What I mean is, instead of using `$comment[0]` or `$comment[1]`, use `$comment['id']` or `htmlspecialchars($comment['text'])`

Comment: The reason I said "trying" to use your code is I found it to be deficient by reason of the suggestions at the bottom of my answer. Especially because I couldn't tell which data field was which when you're accessing them via index like [0] or [1].

Comment: thanks a lot for even trying to read through my code. its chicken scratch and i should have gone through it before posting. my only thing with this method is there is a second query and it's stuck inside a loop. if there are hundreds of comments thats a lot of queries hitting the database.

Comment: ps: at least you tried and put all the code in there, which was very nice compared to others who don't put any code or an insufficient listing. with this sample, helping was easy :)

Comment: to answer your question about "hundreds of queries".. right now, I was way more worried about you just getting the data out *AT ALL*. I'd like to request that you verify you can get this working, then I suggest making a post of another question that's focused on optimization, including how many parent comment rows there are and how many average reply rows per comment. Then, I'd be totally game to take that one on as well.

Comment: thanks zanlok. i know this works because im using something in a more controlled fashion where i know how many rows there will be and an approximation of the amount of data in there. i'd like to eventually replace that with something more efficient.